# AM Charts 5: Export menu always showing, toggle not working

Tags: javascript, amcharts5

I have created a world chart map that takes in heat data and displays it. I have also created an export and annotation menu based on the AM Charts documentation

JS:

```
        // Create root
        var root = am5.Root.new("mainHeatMap");

        // Set themes
        root.setThemes([
            am5themes_Animated.new(root)
        ]);

        // Create chart
        var chart = root.container.children.push(
            am5map.MapChart.new(root, {
                layout: root.horizontalLayout,
                projection: am5map.geoEqualEarth()
            })
        );

        // Create polygon series
        var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(
            am5map.MapPolygonSeries.new(root, {
                geoJSON: am5geodata_worldLow,
                valueField: "value",
                calculateAggregates: true,
                exclude: ["AQ"],
            })
        );

        // Set series world map to grey
        polygonSeries.set("fill", am5.color("#999999"));

        polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.setAll({
            tooltipText: "{cname}, {value} trips - {description}"
        });

        polygonSeries.set("heatRules", [{
            target: polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template,
            dataField: "value",
            min: am5.color("#67b7dc"),
            max: am5.color("#00338d"),
            key: "fill"
        }]);

        polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.events.on("click", function (ev) {
            HandleMapClick(ev.target)
        });

        polygonSeries.data.setAll(heatmapData);

        polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.adapters.add("tooltipText", (text, target) => {
            const country = target.dataItem.dataContext.cname;
            if (country && heatmapData.some(data => data.country === country.id)) {
                return text;
            }
            return "";
        });

        var heatLegend = chart.children.push(
            am5.HeatLegend.new(root, {
                orientation: "horizontal",
                startColor: am5.color("#67b7dc"),
                endColor: am5.color("#00338d"),
                startText: String(min),
                endText: String(max),
                stepCount: 10,
                width: am5.percent(50),
                y: am5.percent(100),
                centerY: am5.percent(100)
            })
        );

        heatLegend.startLabel.setAll({
            fontSize: 12,
            fill: heatLegend.get("startColor")
        });

        heatLegend.endLabel.setAll({
            fontSize: 12,
            fill: heatLegend.get("endColor")
        });

        polygonSeries.events.on("datavalidated", function () {
            heatLegend.set("startValue", polygonSeries.getPrivate("valueLow"));
            heatLegend.set("endValue", polygonSeries.getPrivate("valueHigh"));
        });

        // Set up export and annotation
        var exporting = am5plugins_exporting.Exporting.new(root, {
            menu: am5plugins_exporting.ExportingMenu.new(root, {})
        });

        var annotator = am5plugins_exporting.Annotator.new(root, {});

        var menuitems = exporting.get("menu").get("items");

        menuitems.push({
            type: "separator"
        });

        menuitems.push({
            type: "custom",
            label: "Annotate",
            callback: function () {
                this.close();
                annotator.toggle();            
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
    <script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/map.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/geodata/worldLow.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/plugins/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>
```

With this code I get this output where my export/annotation menu is constantly showing and the toggle does not work:

[World heatmap with export/annotation menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FQGN.png)

Is there something I am missing here, maybe with initialising the menu as a child of the root? All of the functionality of the menu works as intended such as downloading images and annotations. The toggle does not work and the menu is always showing, not sure of a way around this.

I tried using an onClick event to trigger something in the console, but that was not working either. Another workaround was hiding the toggle icon, but it does not look good and takes up alot of room on the chart